# How to filter twitter data on two keywords?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to filter twitter data to  listen to all tweets which contain "Chicago Crime" I am using the below line to do so,

myStream.filter(track=['chicago,crime'])

But it is giving me all the tweets which contain Chicago or crime but I am interested in getting tweets that contain Chicago and crime. 
How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The operator `,` stands for `OR`.

A space is `AND`.
So you should try :

```
myStream.filter(track=['chicago crime'])
```

Reference : https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/basic-stream-parameters